# Append div to another div based on form selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, appendchild

I'm trying to move one div (selected through a form) into another div.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the location of the selected div into a reusable variable since it's apparently only declared locally.

The variable returns undefined every time,  the div never moves and I get an uncaught error.

Is there an easy way to fix this code so it will work?

Thank you for your help!

```js
var divsArr = [
 document.getElementById("div1"),
 document.getElementById("div2"),
 document.getElementById("div3"),
 document.getElementById("div4"),
 document.getElementById("div5"),
 document.getElementById("div6"),
 document.getElementById("div7"),
 document.getElementById("div8")
];

function identifyDiv() {
 var selectDiv = document.getElementById("exampleOptions").value;
 for (var i = 0; i < divsArr.length; i++) {
  var location = divsArr[i];
  if (selectDiv == divsArr[i].id) {
   break;
  }
 }
}

function moveDiv() {
 identifyDiv();
 alert(location.id); // debug
 location.appendChild(topDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange">
</div>

<br/>

<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black">
 <div id="div1" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
 </div>
 <div id="div2" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
 </div>
 <div id="div3" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
 </div>
 <div id="div4" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
 </div>
 <div id="div5" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
 </div>
 <div id="div6" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
 </div>
 <div id="div7" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
 </div>
 <div id="div8" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
 </div>
</div>

<br/>

<form style="width: 40px; float: left">
  <select id="exampleOptions" name="Numbers">
    <option id="example1" value="div1">1</option>
    <option id="example2" value="div2">2</option>
    <option id="example3" value="div3">3</option>
    <option id="example4" value="div4">4</option>
    <option id="example5" value="div5">5</option>
    <option id="example6" value="div6">6</option>
   <option id="example7" value="div7">7</option>
  <option id="example8" value="div8">8</option>
 </select>
</form>

<button onclick="moveDiv()">Run Script
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so to keep things clean I thought using `getElementsByClassName` would be a good idea to "group" all the elements together. This still uses the array you wanted but cuts down the needed work as well as keeping things clean.

The class is set on each of the elements with the id's that you were trying to get.

From here it then checks the id and compares like you've set it to do.
Finally it sets the `selected` variable to the selected element you want and then appends the `topDiv` to that

```js
//Get all the divs in an array
var divsArr = document.getElementsByClassName("divGroup");
var selected;
//alert(divsArr.length);

function identifyDiv() {
  //Get value of the select div
  var selectDiv = document.getElementById("exampleOptions").value;

  //alert(selectDiv);

  for (var i = 0; i < divsArr.length; i++) {
    //var location = divsArr[i];
    if (selectDiv === divsArr[i].id) {
      selected = divsArr[i];
      break;
    }
  }
}

function moveDiv() {
  identifyDiv();

  var topDiv = document.getElementById("topDiv");

  alert(selected.id); // debug
  selected.appendChild(topDiv);
}
```

```html
   
  <div id="topDiv" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange">

  </div>

  <br/>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black">
    <div id="div1" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
    </div>
    <div id="div4" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
    </div>
    <div id="div5" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
    </div>
    <div id="div6" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
    </div>
    <div id="div7" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
    </div>
    <div id="div8" class="divGroup" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <form style="width: 40px; float: left">
    <select id="exampleOptions" name="Numbers">
   <option id="example1" value="div1">1</option>
   <option id="example2" value="div2">2</option>
   <option id="example3" value="div3">3</option>
   <option id="example4" value="div4">4</option>
   <option id="example5" value="div5">5</option>
   <option id="example6" value="div6">6</option>
   <option id="example7" value="div7">7</option>
   <option id="example8" value="div8">8</option>
  </select>
  </form>

  <button onclick="moveDiv()">Run Script
 </button>

  <script src="JS/hi.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really like the idea of using the class to group/select the array elements. Never occurred to me I could use classes like that, even if there isn't a corresponding entry in the CSS file. Thanks for that tidbit. Seems, I guess, I needed to declare the variable globally then just reassign in within the function. I missed that.

You know, the more I think about it, the more excited I get about using classes like that. I could actually loop through multiple arrays that way, as long as the elements all have the same class name!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `location` is declared inside a function and is local to that function. In order to be able to used across your code you need to declare it outside.  I've changed the variable name since `location` already is a global variable and may cause confusion.

```js
var selectedDiv;

var divsArr = [
  document.getElementById("div1"),
  document.getElementById("div2"),
  document.getElementById("div3"),
  document.getElementById("div4"),
  document.getElementById("div5"),
  document.getElementById("div6"),
  document.getElementById("div7"),
  document.getElementById("div8")
];

function identifyDiv() {
  var selectDiv = document.getElementById("exampleOptions").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < divsArr.length; i++) {
    selectedDiv = divsArr[i];
    if (selectDiv == divsArr[i].id) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

function moveDiv() {
  identifyDiv();
  alert(window.selectedDiv.id); // debug
  selectedDiv.appendChild(topDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange">
</div>

<br/>

<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black">
  <div id="div1" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
  </div>
  <div id="div2" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
  </div>
  <div id="div3" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
  </div>
  <div id="div4" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
  </div>
  <div id="div5" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
  </div>
  <div id="div6" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
  </div>
  <div id="div7" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: blue">
  </div>
  <div id="div8" style="width: 25px; height: 100px; float: left; background-color: lightblue">
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<form style="width: 40px; float: left">
  <select id="exampleOptions" name="Numbers">
    <option id="example1" value="div1">1</option>
    <option id="example2" value="div2">2</option>
    <option id="example3" value="div3">3</option>
    <option id="example4" value="div4">4</option>
    <option id="example5" value="div5">5</option>
    <option id="example6" value="div6">6</option>
   <option id="example7" value="div7">7</option>
  <option id="example8" value="div8">8</option>
 </select>
</form>

<button onclick="moveDiv()">Run Script
</button>
```

Comment: I've misunderstood the root of the problem. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You got it right. I see now I needed to declare the variable globally and just reassign it in the function. Also, that's good to know about "location." I should have figured that. Still learning. Thanks again!